# Notification's RTL title is aligned to left instead to right

Tags: android, notifications, android-notifications

I have noticed that when I show notification with RTL title or any RTL text it is aligned to left instead of right side.

The problem only occurs when:

- the device language is set to LTR language (e.g. English) and text in notification should be RTL
- on Android 7.1.1 RTL text is aligned to right, but on Android 10 RTL text is aligned to left

Is there a solution to show text with proper alignment no matter the device language?

**How it looks right now:**

[image: RTL notification]

**Code:**

```
val notificationManager = getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
    notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(
       NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, "Test", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH)
    )
}
val builder = NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID).apply {
    setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground)
    setContentTitle("تجربة")
}
notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, builder.build())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to remove `android:supportsRtl="true"`
 from `AndroidManifest.xml`. It was added by default while creating the project.

It is not worth solution, because mirrored RTL layouts in application would be LTR after that change.